# C++/CLI - how to marshal "unsigned int&"?

Tags: c++, .net, frameworks, marshalling, managed

I've got a bunch of C++ functions that I need to wrap with a managed C++ class.
Some of the unmanaged functions return unsigned int values by reference. E.g.:

int func(....., **unsigned int& val**, ......);

I've got two questions:

1. I'd like my wrapping C++ methods to expose "val" for such native functions as unsigned int as well (either "ref" or "out"). What type should I use? "unsigned int %", "UIntPtr^%", something else? How the wrapping method declation will look like?
2. Inside my managed C++ wrapper method, how should I marshal this parameter?
   I've tried multiple combinations along the lines of:

   `marshal_context ctx;
   return origFunc(....., ctx.marshal_as<unsigned int&>(val), ......);`

But I get compiler errors complaining about unsupported conversions.

Comment: Only C++ proper knows what a reference is.  Basically a reference is a C++ thing -- no other language knows what they are.  Instead, you should be passing values or pointers.  Second, there is no specification as to how a reference is implemented underneath the hood.

Comment: A reference parameter is very similar to a non-nullable pointer.

Comment: @PaulMck I have no problem wrapping the same function in C# with DlIImport attribute. In that case I describe the parameter as `ref uint val` for both - the native and wrapping methods.